# return type for Interface-Based Projections

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-projections

I'm learning how to use projection in spring-data-jpa. And i have a problem with projections using interfaces. I saw a lot of tutorial where they just write an interface with the getter they need and finally they just use it as return type for their query and it just work. They can get as response an object with just the needed attributes. But when i try that i get something else. below is my code.

**Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Contact {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToOne
  private Address address;

  public Contact() {
  }

  public Contact(Long id, String name, Address address) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }
}
```

interface based projection:

```java
public interface ContactProjection {
String getName();

AddressSummary getAddress();

interface AddressSummary {
 String getCity();
}
}
```

Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact,Long> {

  Collection<ContactDto> findAllByName(String name);

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM  Contact", nativeQuery = true)
  List<ContactProjection> getAllContracts();
}
```

Controller

```java
  @GetMapping("/contacts/interface")
  public ResponseEntity getAllContactsInterfaceProjection(){
    List<ContactProjection> allContracts = contactRepository.getAllContracts();

    String jsonResponse = JsonMarshal.getInstance().marshal( allContracts  );
    return ResponseEntity.ok(jsonResponse);
  }
```

but insted of getting a response just with the needed attribut here is what i get.

```java
Hibernate: 
    select
        contact0_.id as id1_1_,
        contact0_.address_id as address_3_1_,
        contact0_.name as name2_1_ 
    from
        contact contact0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        address0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        address0_.city as city2_0_0_,
        address0_.country as country3_0_0_ 
    from
        address address0_ 
    where
        address0_.id=?
2021-06-17 21:07:18.101  WARN 98198 --- [l-1 housekeeper] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=5m213ms209µs324ns).
2021-06-17 21:07:18.104 DEBUG 98198 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Failed to complete request: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: de.monticore.montigem.be.domain.cdmodelhwc.classes.ContactProjection. Forgot to register a type adapter?
2021-06-17 21:07:18.105 ERROR 98198 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: de.monticore.montigem.be.domain.cdmodelhwc.classes.ContactProjection. Forgot to register a type adapter?] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: de.monticore.montigem.be.domain.cdmodelhwc.classes.ContactProjection. Forgot to register a type adapter?
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:73) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter$1.write(TypeAdapter.java:191) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:?]
    at de.monticore.montigem.rte.be.marshalling.GsonMarshal.marshal(GsonMarshal.java:101) ~[montigem-be-rte-2.1.0-20210530.133327-1.jar:?]
    at de.monticore.montigem.be.service.rest.RESTApplicationConfig.getAllContactsInterfaceProjection(RESTApplicationConfig.java:98) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

I put a break point to find out what the repository returns , and the picture bellow is what i got.

[debugging overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi7qc.png)

So my question in now how do i do to get just and object with the attributes i wants

Comment: What does `contactRepository.getAllContracts()` do exactly?

Comment: this function is just supposed to return the list of all the contracts. And my goal is now to select just the attributes defined by the ContractProjection interface

Answer (score 0):

### Easy steps you can follow

- I think you should remove this from `ContactProjection.java` class

```java
AddressSummary getAddress();

interface AddressSummary {
 String getCity();
}
```

- After replacing directly by `getCity()` your interface might look like this

```java
public interface ContactProjection {
String getName();
String getCity();
}
```

- Then make change in the repository query like this

```java
  @Query(value = "SELECT name, city FROM  Contact", nativeQuery = true)
  List<ContactProjection> getAllContracts();
```

Hope your issue will be resolved!